# Average of multiple rasters in PostGIS raster?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I am trying to calculate the average of multiple rasters stored as `raster` datatype in PostGIS enabled database. The rasters are stored in three different tables (spi3, sri3, and smdi) and have `date` as common column. I am trying to use [ST_Union](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html) function of PostGIS, where it says we can specify `setof` raster.

This is what I have done so far.

```
select st_union(SETOF[spi3_raster, sri3_raster, smdi_raster], 'MEAN')
from
(
select spi3.raster as spi3_raster, sri3.raster as sri3_raster, smdi.raster as smdi_raster
from spi3 as spi3
join sri3 as sri3
  on spi3.date = sri3.date
  and sri3.date = '2013-01-01'
join smdi as smdi
  on sri3.date = smdi.date
where spi3.date = '2013-01-01'
) as foo;
```

However, I am not getting the result as expected.

Comment: And how is what you are getting not what you are expecting? From the query it would seem the result you are expecting is the mean of the three rasters.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça Yes, I am expecting mean of the three rasters. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: As far as I know. What are you actually seeing? Are you sure your joins are working properly, ie, you are actually inputting 3 bands. Without considerably more information, this question is hard to answer.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça Yes, the joins are working fine. With the only joins, I get three columns with the given name. Each raster is single band gray. But with the union, I am getting error as `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: select st_union(SETOF[spi3_raster, sri3_raster, smdi_raster]...
                                         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
SQL state: 42601
Character: 34`.

Comment: You can do it using SELECT ST_Union (foo.rast, 'mean') FROM (SELECT rast FROM spi3 UNION SELECT rast FROM sri3 UNION SELECT ....) foo. It isn't very elegant, but it works.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça Can you add that as an answer and I can accept it. As you said, it's not very efficient but does the job for me. Just verified using ArcGIS raster calculator as well.

Comment: Sure. If I figure out a more elegant solution, I will update it. However, I checked it, and it doees seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be another way, but you can use UNION SELECT to stack rasters, as you would to combine any other type into a single field containing various rows. So, including the where condition in each select, rather than as a join, you would have

```
SELECT ST_Union (foo.raster, 'mean') 
  FROM (
     SELECT raster FROM spi3 WHERE date='2013-01-01'
      UNION 
     SELECT raster FROM sri3 WHERE date='2013-01-01'
      UNION 
     SELECT raster FROM smdi WHERE date='2013-01-01'
    ) foo;
```

I suspect that there might be a more elegant, but not necessarily more efficient, way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, trying to get the standard deviation of *all* of the values across a selected set of raster layers.  Most existing functions seem to be designed for a single layer. I couldn't use @John Powell's solution because ST_Union() doesn't have a standard deviation function.  My solution uses ST_DumpValues() and it should work for the mean (or any other function) as well:

```
WITH rasts as (SELECT rast from mytable WHERE ...),
vals as (SELECT unnest(ST_DumpValues(rast,1,TRUE)) as val from rasts rs)
SELECT count(val), stddev(val) from vals WHERE val IS NOT NULL
```

`ST_DumpValues()` returns a record that is a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/rowtypes.html) unless you specify the band, as I have done here, and you can alternatively use composite type grammar to get at the elements:
`unnest((st_dumpvalues(rs.rast)).valarray)`

Also, I learned from another answer by John Powell that `exclude_nodata_value=true`, which is the default in ST_DumpValues(), "*doesn't mean return no data, it means return null instead of a numeric value representing no data, such as -9999*;" which is why I added `WHERE val IS NOT NULL`

I haven't tried this solution on a big problem so I don't know how efficient it is.